# $translate, instant. Как с этим работать? Как перевести только какое то слово?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

В контроллере есть $scope который нужно выводить\передавать на определенном языке, не смотря на то какой язык в данный момент выбран пользователем.
Как это реализовать? Как перевести нужный мне кусок(буд то переменная или еще что) на нужный язык?

Читал гайд и нашел что то о instant(translationId, interpolateParams, interpolationId, forceLanguage, sanitizeStrategy)

пока что не могу понять как его использовать.

Answer (score 0):

```
$translate.instant(translationId, interpolateParams, interpolationId, forceLanguage, sanitizeStrategy);
```

- *translationId* - что переводить
- *interpolateParams* - параметры, которые будут использоваться в шаблоне перевода. например если текст перевода будет: `count: {{count}}` можно передать значение, которое будет использоваться вместо count, и получить "count:10", или "count:20"
- *interpolationId* - id специфического интерполятора (если есть)
- *forceLanguage* - язык на который менять
- *sanitizeStrategy* - вид в котором выдаем

Comment: _interpolateParams_ - параметры, которые будут использоваться в шаблоне перевода. например если текст перевода будет: `count: {{count}}` можно передать значение, которое будет использоваться вместо count, и получить "count:10", или "count:20"

Comment: спасибо. добавил